# How to show action bar in a tab group activity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have a tab group activity containing 4 tabs. tab1, tab2, tab3, tab4 and two child activities in tab1. How to display action bar in a child activity2 of tab1. But the action bar is not displaying. I want the action bar to be displayed in one child activity.

activity of tab1

```
public class EntriesTabActivity extends TabGroupActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   startChildActivity("EntriesContentActivity", new Intent(this,EntriesContentActivity .class));
}   
}
```

ChildActivity

```
public class EntriesContentActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // construct the tab host
    setContentView(R.layout.entries_content);

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu_entry, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.iga.allergy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
</uses-permission>

<!-- We must declare these two permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.CHECK_LICENSE" />

<application
    android:name="com.iga.allergy.AJ_Constant"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name="com.iga.allergy.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


    <activity
        android:name="com.iga.allergy.TabController"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.iga.allergy.EntriesTabActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
  <activity
        android:name="com.iga.allergy.EntriesContentActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you are developping with support library since you want actionbar for api8.have you included appcompat_v7 and android-support-v4 to your project properly?

ActivityGroup inherits android.app.activity and I dont think you can add multiple actionbar to childs or fragments but only to the parent activity.so to my point of view its impossible to add an actionbar to child activities.besides activityGroup is deprecated we should use  Fragment and FragmentManager APIs instead.

Comment: Yes. i have included appcompat_v7 and android-support-v4 libraries to my project